# How do I move the window buttons back to the right for all users?

Tags: metacity, window-buttons

I know I can edit gconf to move the [Minimize,Maximize,Close] buttons back to the right-hand side, but is there a way to do this for all users?

Ideally at install time so I don't have to explain this to every user every time I set up a new machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about install time, but when new users are created, the files from `/etc/skel` are copied to the new home directory. You could add a file

```
/etc/skel/.gconf/apps/metacity/general/%gconf.xml
```

with the contents

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gconf>
<entry name="button_layout" mtime="1273173410" type="string">
    <stringvalue>:minimize,maximize,close</stringvalue>
</entry>
</gconf>
```

to `/etc/skel`.

Or you could create the perfect user-setup (let's name him `perfectuser`) on a new account, and replace

```
SKEL=/etc/skel
```

with

```
SKEL=/home/perfectuser
```

in `/etc/adduser.conf`.

That way, each new user you create would have the same configuration as `perfectuser`.

Maybe the install CD could also be modified in a similar way?

To change the setting for all users, you could write a script that adds

```
<entry name="button_layout" mtime="1273173410" type="string">
    <stringvalue>:minimize,maximize,close</stringvalue>
</entry>
```

to all `/home/[user]/apps/metacity/general/%gconf.xml`.

Answer (score 6):

gconf-editor has an option to do this. Just right-click on a value you want to set for all users, and click "Set Default". PolicyKit will open and ask you for your password. After that every new user will have that value.

Comment: This is really good to know, but I accepted ParanoiaPuppy's answer as that one has the virtue of being scriptable.

Answer (score 3):

Download [UbuntuTweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) go to Window Manager Settings and click "Right"

Edit: I'm not exactly sure if this does it for all users but it is easy.

Comment: I may advise certain users to do this as switching themes can sometimes cause the buttons to shift back to the left. But I'm sure it doesn't work for all users.

Answer (score 0):

For people arriving late like me when the above solutions may not work anymore, you can also use gsettings for this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'appmenu:minimize,maximize,close'
```

From

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Metacity